# Can I use Surface Pro 4 and Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, tools, drawing-tablet

I recently bought the new Surface Pro 4 with 8 GB RAM and 256 GB SSD. I installed my CS6 Standard Suite yesterday and I was quite impressed how fast illustrator and Co. opened. Unhappily, the pen does not seem to interact with the programs, so there is no pressure sensitivity (which works quite well with One Note or Fresh Paint). Any solution?

Comment: What tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, but unfortunately only the Creative Cloud version of Photoshop and Illustrator are optimized for pen use. I went to Adobe Max 2014 and I learned that there is actually a different "version" of those two apps built specifically for the Surface, with larger buttons, streamlined menus and tools that work great with the pen. I have used them on my Surface Pro 3 during the trial and they did work really well.

Comment: The same here. When I put my touch enabled laptop in tablet mode in Win10, Ai and Ps automatically switch to touch layout. You can find it in the menu under *Workspaces* I believe.